# Delegate of Base Class Not Called for Sub Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing an IOS app. I created a base class to instantiate the serverclass that has a delegate. I have set that delegate in the init method. I was expecting that the delegate would be set for all sub classes but for some reason that has not happened. The code is as follows.
BaseClass.h

```
@interface BBBaseCommand : NSObject<SectionCommand,ServerDelegate>
{
    Server *serverObj;
}
- (instancetype)init;
- (void)serverDidReceiveResponse:(NSDictionary *)response;
- (void)serverDidReceiveError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

BaseClass.m

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    serverObj = [[Server alloc]init];
    [serverObj setDelegate:self];
    return self;
}
```

SubClass.h

```
@interface BBBoatSaleCommand : BBBaseCommand
-(void)excute;
-(instancetype)init;
@end
```

SubClass.m

```
-(instancetype)init
{
   self = [super init];
    return self;
}
-(void)excute
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [serverObj BoatSaleParams:params];
}
- (void)serverDidReceiveResponse:(NSDictionary *)response
{
     NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
}
- (void)serverDidReceiveError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"An error occured while retrieving the data, please try again later." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
@end
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    serverObj = [[Server alloc]init];
    [serverObj setDelegate:self];
    return self;
}
```

You never create the self object here.

It should be something like

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    if(self = [super init]){
        serverObj = [[Server alloc]init];
        [serverObj setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```